# Adding Function in isset() not Running PHP Script

Tags: php, function, return

I have a form page where a user fills out their information. When the user submits their info, the function `userName` should return their info in a welcome string `$messageNew`. I've added a function to the `isset()` that should return the value if not empty.

When I remove the function 'userName()' from the script, the script works fine and shows the HTML body. When I add the function in the script, the page comes up blank.

I am trying to practice using functions in PHP to return values. I know there is something missing in the function (either syntax/logic?) but I can not figure out what it is. Any input would be appreciated in letting me know what is missing in my script.

Here is the PHP (along with the HTML)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $first = $_POST['firstName'];
    $number = $_POST['numberValue'];
    $sentence = $_POST['sentenceValue'];
    $welcome = "Welcome to this site!";

    $show_form = false;

    function userName($first) {

        $messageNew = echo '$first . $welcome';

            if(!empty($first)) {
                return $messageNew;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
    } // end function userName


}

    else {
        $show_form = true;
        $error_message = "";    
    }


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Lesson6</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
    if($show_form) {
?>
<form name="userForm" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER[ 'PHP_SELF' ]?>">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value="<?php echo $first ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter a number between 100 & 200:</td><td><input type="text" name="numberValue" id="numberValue" value="<?php echo $number ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter a sentence of at least 20 characters:</td><td><input type="text" name="sentenceValue" id="sentenceValue" value="<?php echo $sentence ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p><?php echo $error_message ?></p>
                <p><?php echo $messageNew ?></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<?php
    } else {
?>

    <p><?php echo $welcome; ?></p>

<?php
    } 
?>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page comes up empty because you have an error and don't have error reporting turned on. So start by doing that.

(Warning, your code is a trainwreck)

Your error is you are using `echo` in a variable assignment. You can't and don't need to do that. Just assign the string to the variable.

Also, you are trying to use `$welcome` even though it is not available to your function due to scope. You need to pass it as a parameter to `userName()` just like you do `$first` (I don't know why you did one and not the other).

Also, you try to use both values *before* you check if they are valid. That's *backwards*.

Additionally, you have variables inside single quotes. They are *not* interpolated there. Use double quotes.

Even further, you don't use the concatenation operator inside of strings. You use them to concatenate strings.

```
function userName($first, $welcome) {
        if(!empty($first)) {
            $messageNew = "$first $welcome";
            return $messageNew;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

You can also shorten this by returning the string directly:

```
function userName($first, $welcome) {
        if(!empty($first)) {
            return "$first $welcome";
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: *choo choo, bang* - si.

Comment: I thought you'd never change that `;` for "don't" lol was going to edit but you got it first ;-)

Comment: fyi logs are very helpful to both you and us.

How are you running this? (i.e. php's built in server, apache, nginx?)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I *constantly* type `;` instead of `'`. I mean it's *bad*.

Comment: @John Conde perfect, thanks for your feedback. The error reporting does help. I've haven't had much practice in using return functions, especially in PHP - was not familiar with the concatenation/echo rules. 

If youd like to leave anymore feedback on how I can make my code better, I'd be happy to take your advice. Thanks again.